# Is it possible for an object with more than 3 dimension to exist in a 3D space?

Tags: geometry, spacetime-dimensions

I understand that it is possible for 4D objects to exist in a 3-D space. I also speculate that 5D objects cannot exist in a 3D space? Is there a reason to this limitation (assuming there is a limitation)? And I don't understand how it is possible for a higher dimension object (4D) to exist in a lower dimension space (3D).
I was trying to look at this from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: *I understand that it is possible for 4D objects to exist in a 3-D space.* Where did you get that understanding?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you mean here.  3D objects are very commonly represented in 2D e.g. on your TV, a photograph, or your retina.  Our brains are using to extrapolating an object's 3D structure from this 2D representation.  I would not say that 3D objects exist in 2D because of this, just that a representation is possible.  Usually, this is some form of [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) (a mathematical map which loses one or more dimensions).  It is possible to lose more than one dimension see [Tesseract (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract).  Our brains don't extrapolate the 4D form so well as we don't have the same experience of 4D objects.

Often, this extrapolation goes wrong as [Escher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._C._Escher) drawings and many other optical illusions demonstrate.  Another example is on the Moon where it is hard to distinguish between dips and lumps without the usual shadow gradations caused by the atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical perspective, expressing what an object "is" can be done in a various number of ways. For instance, to express what a tennis ball is I can say "tennis ball", and this consists out of the letter array `[t,e,n,n,i,s,_,b,a,l,l]` which you can represent with a one-dimensional vector.

However, if you want to express the size of the tennis ball and its full shape, with all the bumps inside it, and its exact location, you would need a richer description. One thing you could try is write a very large book that fully describes the tennis ball in all its detail, and where it is located in space with regards to the movement of the Earth or of the Sun or to the galaxy's center. It would be a long book, but it would still be a one-dimensional representation.

One problem with that approach is that you would not be able to do a lot of calculation with that description. Suppose you want to define what happens to two tennis balls with those descriptions when they collide, it would be impossible to define any "rules". It would also be difficult to say whether or not two tennis balls are the same. You can't do any operations on the stream of letters that describe the tennis balls in a way that you can map to the same system of letters.

Therefore, it's easier to just describe the tennis ball in coordinates in three dimensional space. This allows you to perform algebraic routines, calculations, that can be re-interpreted in that coordinate system.

Now, if you consider the tennis ball to consist out of molecules that wiggle around respecting thermodynamical laws, you would need even more data to describe all of the molecules in all of the fibers of the tennis ball and their current state. A molecule is more than just a point in a position, it consists out of a certain state, which it got, historically.

You can describe that state of each molecule using a whole sentence that describes it, in one dimension, or you can again use different dimensions that allow you to use algebraic and calculation rules that end up making sense in the dimensional system you chose. If you do so, your tennis ball would be described in a multi-dimensional system.

But, any dimensional system you choose is allowed to describe the tennisball, a "dimension" is nothing more than part of a semantic rule you set out for defining something, and is used to allow algebraic calculations to be defined in simple ways because these operations are attuned to these systems.

With that in mind, your question becomes "is it possible to describe an object that was described in 5 dimensions, in 3 dimensions"? And the answer is obviously YES, you would just end up either losing extraneous data, or lose some of the mathematical tooling capability. 
If you're lucky, you would not lose any data and would unlock new mathematical tools that can be used in the lower-dimensional space without any loss of information. This would probably not happen with the tennis ball but it may happen for other descriptions of reality.